# Is there a way to perform a cli command while editing a file in NERDTree(vim)?

Tags: linux, vim, command-line-interface, nerdtree

I'd like to do a `grep -r -l "index.php"` while inside vim.  I am using the NERDTree plugin too.  I've tried the command `:!` but after this it states

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I try to type a command in and it immediately reverts back to vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to run an external command, you can prefix it with `:!`

In your case,

```
:!grep -r -l "index.php"
```

ie, your supposed to type the command(s) after `:!` while you're in vim itself.

Using `vimgrep`, you can do

```
:vimgrep /\cindex\.php/ **
```

Do check the examples given in [vim-tips-working-with-external-commands](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442419-vim-tips-working-with-external-commands)

> but after this it states "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

This is the expected result. For grep command, you can see the results on top of this line.

Do checkout `vimgrep`, `Silver Searcher` etc for a better workflow. Some links to familiarize them

[Faster Grepping in Vim](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/faster-grepping-in-vim)
[Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)

Comment: yes. this is the answer.  I only wish I could copy/paste the results.  thanks!

Comment: @IsaacPak: How about adding copy/paste of results as comment, I'll add that to my answer. Also take a look at `vimgrep`. It can really increase productivity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean 'adding copy/paste' results as comment.  I am reviewing the links you submitted and am seeing the power of vimgrep.

Answer (score 1):

Without plugins:

```
:vimgrep \cindex.php **
```

(`\c` forces `ignorecase`; `**` is "all files in this directory and below")

With [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) and [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim):

```
:Ack -i index.php
```

With [the_silver_searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) and [Ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim):

```
:Ag -i index.php
```

You can also add in NERDTree integration using [NERDTree-Ack](https://github.com/tyok/nerdtree-ack) and [NERDTree-Ag](https://github.com/taiansu/nerdtree-ag).

Comment: I tried :vimgrep \cindex.php ** but got E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter

Comment: @IsaacPak It is best to use the a delimiter when using `:vimgrep` and staring your pattern with a alphanumeric character. e.g. `:vimgrep /\cindex\.php/ **`.

Comment: @PeterRincker your code works, but it only shows 1 line with results scrolling and then ending with a count.  I hope that makes sense.  Is there a way to have the results listed out?

Comment: `:vimgrep`/`:grep`/`:make` add locations to the quickfix list. You can navigate this list via `:cnext`/`:cprev`. You can also use `:copen` to open the quickfix window to see the list directly. There is a good Vimcasts episode on this subject: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker, on a business trip so not much connectivity.